# adding borders to the screen in swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am creating a game using swift in Xcode , and i have a ball in the screen the moves on the left side of the screen "upwards" , and the user makes the ball jump every time they click on the screen , but now what i want is to  add a physics body to the left side of the screen , but it doesn't work .

Heres my code for the left side of the screen .

```
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(1 ,self.frame.size.height))
    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(ground)
```

here my code for the right side of the screen .

```
    groundRight.position = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
    groundRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(1 , self.frame.size.height))
    groundRight.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(groundRight)
```

so basically , i want to prevent the ball from falling through the screen on the left side and preventing the user to click to much to make the ball go through the screen on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I believe it's a glitch in the newer XCode Versions from what I've read online. Try to downgrade to an earlier version of XCode.